# AWS IOT to third party DynamoDB service

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot

Using a AWS IOT Rule functionality I can define a rule that maps MQTT data to DynamoDB. Is it possible instead of using local DynamoDB on the same account use a third party DynamoDB resource from a different account to achieve the same result? If positive, how it can be achieved?

Comment: same here. you found solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cross-account credentials to access resources belonging to another AWS account in an IoT rule. This process is described in detail in the [blog here](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/iot/access-cross-account-resources-using-aws-iot-rules-engine/).